# Grade Build Failed on remote server (codeship CI)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradlew

my app is building normally under Android Studio (gradle) but fails to compile when I use it on cloud server (Codeship Continious Integration). 
I start "gradlew assembleRelease" and get this below (do not even get what is the error there!):

> Configuring > 0/2 projects > root
>   project/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.0/asm-tree-4.0.jar
>
> > Configuring > 0/2 projects > root project > 4 KB/21 KB downloaded7 KB/21 KB downloaded11 KB/21 KB downloaded5 KB/21 KB downloaded9 KB/21
> >     KB downloaded21 KB/21 KB downloaded> Configuring > 0/2 projects > root
> >     project > Compiling script into cache1/2 projects > :app > Compiling
> >     script into cache > Resolving dependencies ':app:classpath' >
> >     Compiling script into cache2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2
> >     projectsFAILURE: 
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projectsBuild failed with an exception.
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects occurred configuring project ':app'.
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects> 
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projectsent variable.
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects--stacktrace
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects--info
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects--debug
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projectsore log output.
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projectsBUILD FAILED
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projectse: 14.805 secs
> >     Configuring > 2/2 projects

Answer (score 0):

Explanation found (thanks Codeship for quick support) - Codeship does not support Android Builds as for now ;(